# What is the difference between two routes in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I just create two routes:

```
$r->any  ( '/api/v:api', [ api => qr/\d+/ ], { api => 1 } )->partial( 1 );
$r->under( '/api/v:api', [ api => qr/\d+/ ], { api => 1 } );
```

It seems both work same.

What is the difference under hood between them?

**UPD**
I have noticed that for first case (`->any`) link to static files are moved to `/api/v1`. This is noticeable when exception happen. `mojo/debug` template tries to load static files from `/api/v1/...` path and not `/...`. **Why?**

Answer (score -1):

The `under` is called before anything else. You can place authentication code inside it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

under sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $api_key = $self->req->url->to_abs->username;
    my $api_secret = $self->req->url->to_abs->password;

    if($api_key ne "Admin" && $api_secret ne "Password123") {
        $self->res->headers->www_authenticate('Basic');
        $self->render(text => 'Error: API-Credentials are wrong', status => 401);
        # No routes will be executed
        return undef;
    }

    # Authentication with success, execute other routes
    return 1;
}

# Only executed if the url is http://Admin:Password123@127.0.0.1:3000
any '/' => sub  { 
    my $self = shift; 
    my $date = Mojo::Date->new; 
    $self->render(text => $date, status => 200);
};
```

It's very important that you have to place under above the routines you want to protect.

Comment: What about `any` with `partial` match? prons/cons

Comment: 'any' can take HTTP methods to match while under cannot.  $r->any(['GET', 'POST']). What's your API doing when I send a HTTP request with DELETE? Are the same resources returned when accessed with POST? That's a bad API design.